# How to high res 360-Video streaming in Unity (VR/Android)

Tags: unity-game-engine, nginx, virtual-reality, 360-degrees

My goal is to display 360-degree Video in a VR-Application running on an android based standalone VR-Headset (Pico 4). I have to create my own solution, since my users will mark points (location and time) in different video clips, which is a feature missing from the usual video streaming apps.

My current approach does not allow for smooth video playback with files, that work fine with other video playback solutions.

My approach is to use the Unity VideoPlayer, rendering to the SkyBox. The video is served from a NAS with a nginx server via http. This works great vor very low res video but does not run smooth with the intended video format/bandwith (4096 × 2048, HEVC at 25Mbit/s) even though the hardware should easily support this (Qualcomm XR2, Maximum - 7680 * 4320 resolution, 60fps, 50Mbps, H.264/H.265). Adding to that, other video playback solutions handle even higher res files without lag.

Am I heading in the right direction and have to look for performance losses in my application, or is the general approach via http the real problem? I am grateful for hints in any direction!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.